# Django redirect to specific URL after Registration

Tags: django

Good day.

I'm trying to redirect a user to specific url which in my case is `rootPath/dashboard/`

But when the user registers i get redirected to `/user/register/dashboard/`

I have searched other stackoverflow topics on same problem but they didn't resolve my problem.

I have defined these settings in `settings.py`

```
LOGIN_URL = 'user/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = 'user/logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard/'
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            email = data['email']
            pwd = data['password']
            user = User(email=email, password=pwd)
            user.save()
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context={'form': form})



@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'user/dashboard.html')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('user/logout/', auth_logout, name='logout'),
    path('user/register/', register, name='register'),
    path('dashboard/', dashboard, name='dashboard')

]
```

**register.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container text-center">
        {% if form.errors %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Register</h1>
        <form class="form-signin" action="." method="post">
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p><input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary"></p>
            {#        <a href="{% url 'user:forgot-password' %}"><input type="button" value="Forgot Password"></a>#}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect to any specific url with [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) like this

```
 return redirect('dashboard') #return redirect('url_name')
```

if the `app_name` is provided it would be like this

```
 return redirect('app_name:url_name')
```

Comment: I've changed the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to `'app_name:url'` and it worked